# Ionic 4: how to hide ScrollBar in ion-content

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to hide the scroll-bar in ion-content (Ionic 4)
there's no ion-scroll on ionic 4 so I used the ion-content
but I can't find any css attribute to hide it (most of them not work)

*I do want to scroll but I don't want to see the scrollbar*

```
::-webkit-scrollbar,
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

I've tried it but it doesn't work in ion-content.

Answer (score 23):

Because of Ionic use shadow DOM for ion-content, should disable scroll in element on shadow DOM and after that make ion-content his own scroll and then hide scroll bar for ion-content. The result's ion-content with the hidden working scroll bar.
Need to use [CSS Custom Properties](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content#css-custom-properties). Add styles to global scope.

```css
ion-content {
  // overwrite inline styles
  --offset-bottom: auto!important;
  --overflow: hidden;
  overflow: auto;
  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should add "scrollbar-width: none;" for Firefox :)

Comment: Of course, you right if it is firefox. I guess for android and ios uses WebView component is based on the Chromium. That's why it can be missed.

Comment: This solution hides the scrollbars but blocks the <ion-content> scrollToTop and scrollToBottom function stopped working for me. Is it same for you as well?

Comment: It also blocks infinite scrolling ;(

Comment: I used overflow: hidden on my end to make it work :)

Answer (score 10):

In Ionic 4 you must use following, because Ionic use shadow DOM:

global.scss

```
.no-scroll {
    --overflow: hidden;
}
```

and in page

```
<ion-content class="no-scroll">
```

Comment: This disables scrolling too, it does not just hide the scroll bar.

Comment: This worked superbly! And I can't see any scrollbar as well... I spent hours for this in ionic 4 because all scrolling attributes of the previous version were deprecated. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar,
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
display: none;
}

ion-content {
 --offset-bottom: auto!important;
 --overflow: hidden;
 overflow: auto;
 &::-webkit-scrollbar {
   display: none;
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar, *::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ion-content {
  overflow: hidden;
  --overflow: hidden;
}

.scroll-content {
  overflow: hidden;
}
  ion-infinite-scroll.md.infinite-scroll-enabled.hydrated {
      overflow: scroll!important;
      height: 100%!important;
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, seems to work fine so far while preserving all functionality in Ionic 5.

```css
// variables.scss

ion-content {
  width: calc(100% + 15px);
}
ion-content::part(scroll) {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: This is a super hacky solution, but it was the only one that hide the scrollbar and preserved scrolling functionality... So good job

Answer (score 3):

The `<ion-content>` is a custom element with shadom DOM. There's something called the [::part pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part) to target an element in a shadom DOM element.
If you look at the  shadow dom, you will see this:

[image: ion-content]

Take notice of the `part="scroll"`. Ionic did add [parts](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/753fd2f910e718438e3ac918e2f129501d8e9791/core/src/components/content/content.tsx#L14) to their elements that we can use via the `::part` pseudo element to target this and apply our custom css to hide the scrollbar:

```
ion-content::part(scroll)::-webkit-scrollbar {
   display: none;
}
```

Tested this on iOS and Android successfully. I'm not getting it to work on Chrome though.

Comment: This works for me in Chrome too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59838653/1603234

Answer (score 2):

I have confirmed the following solution works in Ionic 5 although i do believe this should work in Ionic 4 as well.

As others here have noted, the scrollbar which controls the scrolling of content inside of an `ion-content` component exists in the shadow DOM within it and thus you need to target the scrollbar using `::part()` CSS pseudo-element.

In your global style sheet add the following css declarations which will hide the scrollbar while retaining the ability to scroll:

```
/* chrome, safari */
ion-content::part(scroll)::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
/* firefox */
ion-content::part(scroll) {
  scrollbar-width: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @rostislav

Your solution even don't suggested by WebStorm and draw yellow underline in the meaning of warning, but work for me and work, it's awesome :)

solution: add these lines to both `global.scss` and `variables.scss`:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar, *::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ion-content {
  overflow: hidden;
  --overflow: hidden;
}

.scroll-content {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

*NOTIC:* then clear browser cache and refresh page, it's great!

but don't forget that scroll disabled in all pages, add this code to only `.sccs` file of pages that  don't need to be scrolled!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add scroll-y="false" attribute. Go the same issue, this fixed it.

```
<ion-content scroll-y="false">Content here</ion-content>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hack? https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17685

```
<ion-content>
<div style="background-color: #f2f2f2 !important; height: 100vh; overflow: auto;">
# content here
</div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: This "hack" only works when you aren't using an ion-header or anything else outside ion-content.

Answer (score 0):

Refactored @Sergey Oleynikov solution and it worked perfectly for me

```
ion-content {
  // overwrite inline styles
  // --offset-bottom: auto !important; 
  --overflow: hidden;
  overflow: auto;

  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: It also blocks scrolling

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a reliable way to do this using the previously mentioned methods, they either didn't work or stopped the scrolling all together. My approach was to make the ion-content window wider than the screen.

```css
.noscroller {
  left: -10px;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove the scroll dynamically. You can use the approach of removing the `scroll-y` class from shadowDOM at `<main class="inner-scroll scroll-y"></main>` within `<ion-content></ion-content>`.

Firstly, `import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core'` in your `constructor(renderer: Renderer2)`

To reach this, in your `your-component.component.ts` at event cycle  `ngAfterViewInit` or onward.

This will remove the scroll from the page activated in your app.

```
 for(let el of  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".ion-page:not(.ion-page-hidden) ion-content")))
  {
    this.renderer.removeClass(el.shadowRoot.querySelector("main[part=scroll]"), "scroll-y");
    
  }
```

This will add the scroll from the page activated in your app.

```
for(let el of  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".ion-page:not(.ion-page-hidden) ion-content")))
  {
    this.renderer.addClass(el.shadowRoot.querySelector("main[part=scroll]"), "scroll-y");
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Code from spicemix worked! I pasted the code in global.scss and not in variables.scss

```css
/* global.scss */
ion-content {
  width: calc(100% + 15px);
}
ion-content::part(scroll) {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it works after adding the no-scroll class in the `<IonContent>` element, as mentioned above, and after adding the following lines

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const style = document.createElement("style");
  style.innerHTML = ".inner-scroll.scroll-y.overscroll { overflow: initial; }";
  ionContent.current.shadowRoot.appendChild(style);
}, []);
```

Then in the render `<IonContent ref={ionContent} className="no-scroll">...</IonContent>`

The thing is that in these classes `inner-scroll` and `scroll-y` there is a `overflow: hidden;` style so we just have to override it.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you can use
`slot="fixed"`
to make the element fixed thus removing the scroll bar by default for you.

Refer  [ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content)