# Ionic 4 - Remove Scroll Bar

Tags: ionic4

What is the best method to remove the scroll bar in Ionic 4 while still keeping the ability to scroll and using the shadow DOM?

```
::-webkit-scrollbar,
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

This above has no effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Try this it will work fine for me in ionic 4**

```
ion-content {
--offset-bottom: auto!important;
--overflow: hidden;
overflow: auto;
&::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
}
```

Comment: This solution hides the scrollbars but blocks the <ion-content> scrollToTop and scrollToBottom function stopped working for me. Is it same for you as well?

Comment: @Hemang.  yes..i also faced it, for me hiding the scrollbars is at-most important so i didn't focus on scrollToTop and scrollToBottom function.

Comment: Worked for me in ionic 6

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions would disable my scrollbar. What fixed it for me was replacing my ion-contents with divs and adding this in app.scss

```
div {
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* Edge, Internet Explorer */
  scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

// hides scrollbars while allowing to scroll
div::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
}
```